# Am I allowed to build and help a website that sells restaurant equipment, including equipment such as wine fridge?

Tags: halal-haram

I have a new project as a website developer to build a website for a restaurant supplies business.

They sell everything you need for a restaurant (ex: knives, uniforms, shelves, machines)

I noticed they also sell things like a wine fridge (empty) and bar equipment like a shaker.

Note: they only have a handful of products that might be used for haram (ex: a wine fridge) but it can also be used for halal (ex: to store non alcoholic beverages)

I found online source here that if the business doesn't specialise in haram (ex: they specialise in selling alcohol), it is allowed:

https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/395065/designing-restaurant-or-hotels-that-may-include-places-for-alcohol

But they don't have any specific reference.

Not sure what's the ruling here, please help.

Thank you

Comment: If you are a freelance or consultant developer, I'd recommend you to be on the safe side and look for another project.  Allah will bless you with more than you imagine. Ameen

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to decline the project due to:

The business sells restaurant equipment, but it also sells equipment that is specifically used to serve and store alcohol.

Yes those equipment can be used to serve and store any other beverage, but I know for sure that people will buy it for alcohol due to nature of the product.

For example: there is a regular fridge, and there is a wine fridge

Wine fridge has special features that makes it suitable to store wine and restaurants will for sure be using it to store wine.

I don't want to be involved in anything related to alcohol.

My advice to anyone facing a similar situation:

Are the products / services going to be used for haram? just don't do it.

Jakum Allah Khairan people here who made me realise this mistake before it went any further.

Comment: May Allah provide us halal earnings and make us content with what he has decreed.

Answer (score -1):

It is prohibited. It is not permissible to work in that field or to help with it in any way whatsoever, whether that is by manufacturing equipment that is used for such purposes, or maintaining it, or selling it, and so on, because that comes under the heading of helping in sin, encouraging it and approving of it. Allah, may He be exalted, says:

> “Help you one another in Al-Birr and At-Taqwa (virtue, righteousness
> and piety); but do not help one another in sin and transgression. And
> fear Allah. Verily, Allah is Severe in punishment”
>
> [al-Maa’idah 5:2]

Comment: Thanks for sharing Riyaz

Let's say you help someone sell knives, it can be used to cut halal or haram meat.

Does this apply here too? the kitchen and restaurant equipment can be used for both halal and haram and the business does not specialise in haram (ex: they dont sell specifically alcohol equipment)

Comment: thank you for sharing @Muslim, please explain to me your opinion using your intellect

Comment: @anon1010 BarakAllahu feek. Allah hasn't prohibited manufacturing and selling of knives but he has prohibited intoxicants. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: thanks for sharing @Riyaz, yes I understand. they are not selling intoxicants, they are selling 2 items that can be used to store or mix intoxicants but they can also be used to store or mix everything else

Comment: okay I see @Muslim, yes the fact that we know that these products can be used for intoxicants and how many people will be served from it is very bad...

now there is another challenge, I have already verbally agreed to this project and the client is a family member, how can I deal with this in a way that doesn't hurt the family?

Comment: Those 2 items that you are referring to are for general purpose then there is no problem. But if those two items are specific to store and use only for intoxicants then this is haraam.